How to Set Up Dev Environment Through SSH to remote Desktop's WSL?
I'm seeking advice on setting up a development environment given some constraints. Here's our current setup:

We have a laptop with low permissions, and we can only install VSCode on it.
We can use Remote Desktop to connect to a remote Windows Server which has full permissions and already has WSL2 configured.
The Remote Desktop connection is limited to 2 users due to licensing issues.

Our goal is to have our development team(more than 2 users) use the laptop to remotely SSH into the WSL of the remote Windows Server. Here's a text-based diagram of our setup:
+-------------------+      Remote Desktop      +-------------------+
|    Developer's    | -----------------------> |   Remote Windows  |
|      Laptop       |                          |      Server       |
| (Low Permissions) |                          | (Full Permissions)|
|                   |                          |                   |
|  - VSCode         |                          |  - WSL2 Configured|
+-------------------+                          +-------------------+
        |                                              |
        |                                              |
        |                                              |
        +------------------ SSH -----------------------+
                           (Goal)


If you don't have OpenSSH installed on the Developer's machine, that will be tough to accomplish.

@Ramhound, we can create a ticket to ask IT team to install it(one time request is ok).
